# Inequality produced by $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient

Tags: optimization, lipschitz-functions

[Here](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2016/08/5590.pdf) they say:

> If the first derivative of $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous, then
> $$f(y)\leq f(x)+\langle \nabla f(x),y-x\rangle+\dfrac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2.$$

I don't understand how that's true from the fact that $\nabla f$ being $L$-Lipschitz continuous. I know that $\nabla f$ being $L$-Lipschitz continuous implies that $\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|\leq L\|f(x)-f(y)\|$, but I don't know how to derive the other inequality.

Certainly $\|y-x\|^2\geq 0$, but what do we know about the other terms? I'd appreciate if someone can give me a hint how to show that or forward some resource.

Comment: Where is $\nabla f$ evaluated in your formulae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$g(t)= f(x)-f( x+t(y-x))+\langle \nabla f(x),y-x\rangle t+\dfrac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2t^2$$ on $[0,1]$

You see that $$
\begin{align}g'(t)&= \langle \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(x+t(y-x)),y-x\rangle+L\| y-x\|^2t
\\
&\ge - \|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(x+t(y-x))\| \|x-y\|+L\|y-x\|^2t  
\\
&\stackrel{\text{Lipschitz}}{\ge} -L \| t(y-x)\| \|y-x\|+L\|y-x\|^2t=0
\end{align}$$
Hence $g$ is increasing on $[0,1]$, hence $g(1) \ge g(0)=0$.
$\square$

Comment: I am sorry, but there are multiple parts I don't understand. Why do you define $g(t)$ that way?. Also, how does $g$ being increasing show that inequality I initially was asking for?

Comment: For the first question: I replaced $y$ with $x+t(y-x)$. This is the usual approach we use to transform a multidimensional problem to a unidimensional problem, for which we have a lot of available tools. For example, in the above inequality, it's clearly easier to prove a inequality with one real variable $t$, than with a vector $y$

Comment: For your second question, remind that $$g(1)= f(x)-f(y)+\langle \nabla f(x),y-x\rangle +\dfrac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One more question, on the second line, the term should be $||y-x||$ instead of $||x-y||$, right?

Comment: They are the same, right?

Comment: Yes, they are going to be the same. It's a norm. Sorry for my confusion.